# .Net Core Hosting with HTTPS on Nginx with LetsEncrypt Cert

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, https, kestrel-http-server

I currently have my project running http without any issues. Now I am working on encrypting my traffic by using https. I have a certificate for my domain and I set up all the code and areas I thought were necessary to deploy it as https.
When I do this and run it my web page is not displayed, I just get the default nginx page. When I do this with http my web page is displayed.
I've used a few articles on here to setup mine the way I currently have it so now im assuming i'm missing just some small detail that is why my https isn't working.
Here are all the steps I used  for setting up my certificate and deploying it as HTTPS:

```
    1.  .Net Core Project.
Appsettings.json I added these 2 sections.
“Kestrel”: {
    “Endpoints”: {
        “Http”: {
            “Url”: “http://localhost:60110”
        },
        “Https”: {
            “Url”: “https://localhost:60111”
        }
    }
},
“https_port”: 60111

2.  Program.cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls(@“http://*:60110”)
                    .UseUrls(@"https://*:60111")
               .UseKestrel();
                });
3.  Startup.cs
I added app.UseHsts();

4.  Nginx I have 2 vhost files. 1 is for my ‘listen 80;” which works.
My 2nd is this :
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate      /path/to/fullchain.pem #managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem    #managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/websiteFolder;

    server_name MyDomain.tech

    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://localhost:60111;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

5. I setup the symbolic link in nginx/sites-enabled from sites-available
   I did the sudo nginx -t and my syntax passes.
   I also did the nginx -s reload to reload all my conf and vhost files on nginx.

What am I missing or did I do wrong?
Thank you all.

UPDATE:
One thing I found out last night.
I found out one issue, I still haven't solved this yet but..

because I have:

```
.UseUrls(@"https://*:60111")
```

My service was unable to start on ubuntu. It said it could not find the certificate.
So I am going to remove this line and see what happens.
I read that I should only need to declare my certificate on the web server [nginx] and not have to do it twice. [.net & nginx]

if this doesnt work I also want to try on my nginx vhost conf file. to

```
location / {
         proxy_pass         https://localhost:60111;
```

OR

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:60110;
```

with a possible httpsredirect()